# before_action in application controller not been executed first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

There is a `before_action` `require_signin` in `application_controller` in Rails 4.2 `engine` app. The purpose of this `require_signin` is to check if the user is logged in before any action is executed. Here is `require_signin`:

```
  def require_signin
      if !signed_in?
        sign_out
        redirect_to URI.escape(SUBURI + main_app.signin_path), :notice => t('Login First!')
      end
  end
```

The `sign_in?` is:

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

In `engine's` `application_controller`, there is:

```
class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

    before_action :require_signin
    ..........
end
```

Here is an `engine resource_allocx's` `controller` namespace:

```
require_dependency "resource_allocx/application_controller"

module ResourceAllocx
  class AllocationsController < ApplicationController
  ....
  end
end
```

However, in `create`, a new record is created before the user is kicked out of system asking for login again. Based on the design, if the user is not signed in the `require_signin` should kick out the user in `application_controller` and the `create` should never be executed at all. What have been missed here causing the `require_signin` executed after `create`?

Comment: Any `before_action`s in your other controller? Why is your `ApplicationController` inheriting from `::ApplicationController`? What else aren't you showing here?

Comment: It  is a Rails engine which is inheriting from main app's application controller by default.

Comment: Ok, so add more code/details. Show your namespaces, show your other controller, etc. - the devil is in the details.

Comment: I don't think your `ApplicationController` should be inheriting from itself. Try changing it to `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` and see if that helps.

Comment: Added header of engines controller to the post.

Comment: I have the same issue. The before_actions for the Application Controller in the engine are not being executed at all when it inherits from the main app's application controller, which doesn`t make any sense.